# Converting Double to Time Format

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have a bunch of numbers which I get which are like `1.567` or `22.654` or `220.123` and I want to convert them to time in the `00:00:00.000 (hours/Minutes/Seconds.Miliseconds)`

Any advice on how I can achieve this efficently ?? without too much fiddling.

I need a vb.net solution where possible.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `DateTime.AddHours` method. It takes `double` values as a parameter:

```
Dim d as DateTime = (new DateTime()).AddHours(1.567)
```

Result is `{0001-01-01 01:34:01}`

Then you can use `DateTime.ToString()` method to get time in desired format:

```
Dim s as String = d.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Results is `"01:34:01.200"`

It will work for all values from `0` to `23.99`

**UPDATE**

If your input values represents hours and they can be greater then 24 you can use `TimeSpan` instead of `DateTime`:

```
Dim d as TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(220.123)
Dim s As String = string.Format("{0}:{1}:{2}.{3}", CInt(d.TotalHours), d.Minutes, d.Seconds, d.Milliseconds)
```

Comment: @Teejay : it is possible, though the asker didn't specify what the expected "output" is for the given data.

Comment: This looks like the perfect solution :) Ill let you know how it went.. Thanks

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I thought it, didn't say your answer was wrong :)

Comment: I had to wrap everything in a IF statement by sayiong if the double number was above 60 first divide by 60 and then get the minutes from it ... else just get the time ... (All in all a brilliant solution ) worked really well . Thanks for the help.